# changing site dropdown value with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm coding a little program that access a site with an user and pass, then, inside the profile page, there's a dropdown list with phone numbers, when a number is selcted, the page reloads with difrent data, what I'm trying to do is iterate through all the numbers on the dropdown and save some info from each page.

All I got so far is getting the info from the html, but I have no idea of how change through all the numbers.

```
    <form action="/me/plan" id="form-active-subscriber" method="get">
      <select class="span3" id="current_subscriber" name="current_subscriber">
          <option value="998473069" selected="selected">56951292575</option>
          <option value="998487400">56951231211</option>
          <option value="998473907">56951294007</option>
          <option value="998474581">56951242122</option>
          <option value="998474544">56951240563</option>
          <option value="998487484">56951232281</option>
          <option value="998474580">56951241415</option>
          <option value="998473188">56951286777</option>
    </form>
```

When a value is selected, the URL change to

```
    somthing.com/plan?utf8=✓&current_subscriber=998473907
```

by the way, I'm using beautifulsoup to parse the HTML

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I easily solve it with

```
    html = response.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    numbers = soup.select("option")

    for number in numbers:
        number = number["value"]
        response = self.opener.open(page+"plan?utf8=&current_subscriber="+number, None, 10)
```